# UIMenuController do not hide system items

Tags: ios, swift, uimenucontroller

I show a UIMenuController in a uiviewconroller in this way:

in my class:

```
override open func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}

open override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any) -> Bool {

    //here I check for my custom action, else return false
    return false
}
```

then to show I use:

```
//Make this as first responder
    self.becomeFirstResponder()

    ///Build menu
    let menu = UIMenuController.shared
    ///Set item and anchor point, and showit
    menu.menuItems  = itemsToAdd
    menu.setTargetRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: bubbleNode.view.bounds.size.width, height: bubbleNode.view.bounds.size.height), in: bubbleImageNode.view)
    menu.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
```

the problem is that in a device I show my custom items, but also: "Spell, speak, speck sentence, ecc..." how can I disable it?

Comment: menu has no member delegate

Comment: your control is UITextView?

Comment: is ASCellNode, a collectionviewcell from AsyncDisplayKit

Answer (score 0):

override canPerformAction and handle it for each specific action. It working perfectly for me.

```
 override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {

        var canPerform = super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)

        if (action == "your action to restrict") {
              canPerform = false
        }

        return canPerform
    }
```

Comment: same error... I saw that as soon as the view is loaded, if I long press the view, I see only my custom items, after 1 or 2 seconds, If I longpress again I see my items and the system items

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is "Accessibility" option "speak selection" in my device, if I disabled it, I see only the custom items, but in other app i see only custom items with this option enabled!

Answer (score 0):

```
class TextViewWithCopyAction: UITextView {

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(copy(_:)){
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
        
    }
}
```

**to use it:**

```
let textView: TextViewWithCopyAction = {
    let textView = TextViewWithCopyAction()
    textView.backgroundColor = .white
    return textView
}()
```

Answer (score -2):

If you see *speak* option in `UIMenuController` that is from device go to:

> Setting->Accessibility->Speech->Speech

Select and disable it. Automatically Speak option will get removed from menu.